# Надо синонимизировать метки на темы [перевод] и [локализация]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Есть вот такие две пары меток, которых скорее всего надо синонимизировать:

- [translation](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/translation) (28 вопросов) -> [перевод](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4) (43 вопроса)
- [localization](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/localization) (33 вопроса) -> [локализация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f) (150 вопросов)

Comment: Если быть занудой, то `перевод != локализация`, первый это просто перевод, а вторая это перевод с учетом специфики приложения, контекста интерфейса и даже специфики региона, в котором локализация используется.

Comment: @aepot если быть занудой, то ТС и не предлагает упомянутые тобой метки синонимизировать. Тут отдельные две пары.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

локализация - localization:

```
updating post history, 36 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 33 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 30 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'localization': [localization] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 180
tag remapping of [локализация] and [localization] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym localization -> локализация was approved!
```

translation - перевод:

```
updating post history, 35 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 28 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 27 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'translation': [translation] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 70
tag remapping of [перевод] and [translation] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
1 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym translation -> перевод was approved!
```